# How do I prove the converse of Stone-Weierstrass theorem?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. Let $\bar \rho$ be the uniform metric on $\mathbb{R}^X$ and $\mathscr{A}$ be an $\mathbb{R}$-subalgebra of $C_0(X,\mathbb{R})$ which is dense in $(C_0(X,\mathbb{R}),\bar \rho)$.

In this case, how do I prove that $\mathscr{A}$ separates points on $X$ and $\mathscr{A}$ vanishes nowhere?

I can prove this by applying Urysohnn's Lemma if $X$ is compact, but cannot handle this when $X$ is locally compact.

Comment: Urysohnn's lemma has an analogue for locally compact spaces.

Let $X$ be a locally compact space, and let $K, F ⊂ X$ be two disjoint sets, with $K$ compact, and
$F$ closed. Then there exists a continuous function $f $: $X → [0, 1]$ such that $f_{|K}=1$ and $f_{|F}=1$

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to prove that $C_0(X,\mathbb{R})$ separates points and vanishes nowhere.

Let $\bar X$ be the one-point compactification of $X$ so that $\bar X$ is compact Hausdorff, hence $T_4$, in which Urysohnn's lemma is applicable.

Now, define $\mathscr{C}\triangleq \{f\in C(\bar X,\mathbb{R}): f(\infty)=0\}$.

Note that $\mathscr{C}$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-subalgebra of $C(\bar X,\mathbb{R})$ and there is an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra isomorphism $\phi:\mathscr{C}\rightarrow C_0(X,\mathbb{R}):f\mapsto f\upharpoonright X$.

> Claim1. $C_0(X,\mathbb{R})$ vanishes nowhere.

Proof>

Fix $x\in X$.

Then, there exists $g\in C(Y,[0,1])$ such that $g(x)=1$ and $g(\infty)=0$ by Urysohnn's Lemma.

Hence $g\in \mathscr{C}$ and $g(x)=1$.

Thus $\phi^{-1}(g)\in C_0(X,\mathbb{R})$ and $\phi^{-1}(g)(x)\neq 0$. Q.E.D.

> Claim2. $C_0(X,\mathbb{R})$ separates points.

Proof>

Let $x,y$ be distinct points in $X$.

Then, there exists $g\in C(\bar X,[0,1])$ such that $g(x)=1$ and $g(y)=0$, hence $g(x)\neq g(y)$.

Moreover, there exist $h,k\in \mathscr{C}$ such that $h(x)\neq 0$ and $k(y)\neq 0$.

Define $u\triangleq gk-g(x)k$ and $v\triangleq gh-g(y)h$.

Then, it can be directly checked that $u,v\in \mathscr{C}$ and $u(y)\neq 0$ and $v(x)\neq 0$.

Now, set $f\triangleq \frac{u}{u(y)} + 2\frac{v}{v(x)}$.

Then, $f\in \mathscr{C}$ and $f(x)\neq f(y)$.

Hence the inverse of $f$ under $\phi$ separates $x,y$. Q.E.D.